# ComboBox.SelectedValue getting reset in Windows XP only

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox, portability

I'm having some issues with WinForms `ComboBox` class.  What I am trying to achieve is programmatically setting `SelectedValue` from the `ComboBox.TextChanged` handler once a match is found.  This works fine on Windows 7, but in Windows XP `SelectedValue` will get set and `SelectedValueChanged` will be raised, but then once it reaches `Validating` `SelectedValue` returns `Nothing`.  It seems the only way to change `SelectedValue` in XP is via selecting something from the dropdown.

Here's a toy `Form` with just a `ComboBox` and a multi-line `TextBox`.

XP:  Typed into the `ComboBox` is 1Y, then tab is pressed.  Output:

```
SelectedValueChanged: SelectedValue: 1X
Validating: SelectedValue: Nothing
Value is: 
Validated: SelectedValue: Nothing
```

Win7:  Typed into the `ComboBox` is 1Y, then tab is pressed.  Output:

```
SelectedValueChanged: SelectedValue: 1X
Validating: SelectedValue: 1X
Value is: 1X
Validated: SelectedValue: 1X
```

Code:

```
Public Class ComboBoxXPForm
    Private WithEvents mData As New DataHolder
    Private mBindingSrc As BindingSource


    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        mBindingSrc = New BindingSource() With {.DataSource = mData}

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("value", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("displayValue", GetType(String))

        dt.Rows.Add("", "")
        For i = 1 To 10
            dt.Rows.Add(i & "X", i & "Y")
        Next

        cboBox.DataSource = dt
        cboBox.ValueMember = "value"
        cboBox.DisplayMember = "displayValue"

        cboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", mBindingSrc, "StrVal", True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboBox_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboBox.SelectedValueChanged
        txtDebug.Text &= vbNewLine & "SelectedValueChanged: SelectedValue: " & _
            If(cboBox.SelectedValue Is Nothing, _
               "Nothing", cboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataHolder_DebugInfo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DebugEventArgs) Handles mData.DebugInfo
        txtDebug.Text &= vbNewLine & e.DebugInfo
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboBox.TextChanged
        'For Each row In cboBox.Items
        '    If cboBox.Text = row("displayValue") AndAlso row("value") <> cboBox.SelectedValue Then
        '        'cboBox.SelectedValue = row("value")
        '        cboBox.SelectedItem = row
        '    End If
        'Next
        For i = 0 To cboBox.Items.Count - 1
            Dim item = cboBox.Items(i)
            If cboBox.Text = item("displayValue") Then
                cboBox.SelectedIndex = i
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboBox_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboBox.Validated
        txtDebug.Text &= vbNewLine & "Validated: SelectedValue: " & _
            If(cboBox.SelectedValue Is Nothing, _
               "Nothing", cboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboBox_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles cboBox.Validating
        txtDebug.Text &= vbNewLine & "Validating: SelectedValue: " & _
            If(cboBox.SelectedValue Is Nothing, _
               "Nothing", cboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DebugEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private mDebugInfo As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal DebugString As String)
        MyBase.New()
        DebugInfo = DebugString
    End Sub

    Public Property DebugInfo() As String
        Get
            Return mDebugInfo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mDebugInfo = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DataHolder
    Public Event DebugInfo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DebugEventArgs)

    Private mStrVal As String
    Public Property StrVal() As String
        Get
            Return mStrVal
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mStrVal = value
            RaiseEvent DebugInfo(Me, New DebugEventArgs("Value is: " & value))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: This is a guess, but it seems that the problem was changing `.SelectedValue` inside of `.TextChanged` potentially creating a loop (both triggering each other back and forth).  If `.SelectedValue` is set in `Validating` then it raises no issue in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning AutoCompleteMode to become SuggestAppend, and AutoCompleteSource to become ListItems. Then you can remove the entire TextChanged code block and it should also work properly on XP.

Comment: That led me in the right direction--with `AutoComplete` it sets `SelectedValue` without having to manually do it.  I ended up using `Suggest` though because `SuggestAppend` changes the `.Text` property to the first match, which doesn't work if you want to wait for a match before triggering some behavior.